# vbscript to open excel from current location

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a .bat that call a .vbs that reads from an Excel file here is what i have

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.sleep 2000 

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\folder1\Folder2\MyExcel.xls")
 set objsheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

OBJECT.SendKeys "Some Data."&""&objsheet.Cells(2,1).value &" " &objsheet.Cells(2,4).value
WScript.sleep 200
```

This works great my problem is different people will be using it so i need it to be able to run from the current location (%cd%)

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.Path 
Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

Which returns for example:

C:\Users\d3ll_main\Dropbox\UNICEF CAR 2016\Analysis

C:\Users\d3ll_main\Dropbox\UNICEF CAR 2016\Analysis\UnicefRCA_Analysis_v0.2.2.xlsm

Thisworkbook refers to the workbook where the VBA code lives - irrespective of the active workbook.

Comment: So where would i add that?

Comment: Well this returns a path. So whereever you would otherwise use the path - in your example above, that would be: "C:\folder1\Folder2\MyExcel.xls".

Although I would recommend setting a variable:

Dim myPath as string

myPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName

And then use myPath as a reference.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. Looking at it looks like it goes in Excel? My .vbs is stand alone.

Comment: Well you would import your module in some workbook I presume? In which case it will return the path to that workbook